# call function in superclass from subclass

Tags: actionscript-3, class, subclass

I'm having a small project in Actionscript 3, and everything would be very much easier if it was possible to call code in the superclass from the subclass.

This is the project:

CarGame

        Car

is it possible to call a function in the CarGame class from the Car class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd call them with the *super* statement.

Such as:

```
super.someFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [`super`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/statements.html#super) statement.